# SQL calculate percentage from calculated column

Tags: sql, percentage

I have a table with multiple columns however I need to calculate a Total Percentage based off 2 columns.

Column 1 has unique identifier (number i.e. 15211, 36521, 45987 etc)
Column 2 has a "Y" or is blank (the criteria is built in to the DWH)

What i am wanting to do is get a Percentage of Column 2 of only the Y fields using Column 1 as the Denominator

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 25638 | y |
| 69857 | n |
| 78561 | n |
| 23149 | y |

based on the example above im expecting 2/4 = 0.50 or 50%

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the result of a conditional aggregation on Column2 = 'Y', and the overall count.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Column2 = 'y' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS perc_y
FROM tab
```

Output:

| perc_y |
| --- |
| 0.5000 |

If you want a percentage, multiply by 100, round up and concatenate with '%'.

Here's a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j7kCgeP32GureHXj5m5xQ3/0) in MySQL, although it should work on all the most common DBMS'.

Comment: thanks for all your replies.. unfortunately none of them gave me the desired results which is probably to do with the data configuration on my end. Any how I did sort it eventually by using 'sum(case when [column 2]= 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)*100.0/Count(*) as 'Percentage''